# Is this version of "Samnō miṭra" legitimate? What does it mean?

Tags: mantras

> Shamno mitra sham varunaha
>
> Shamno bhavatva aryamaa
>
> Shamno indro brhspatih
>
> Shamno vishur-urukramaha.
>
> Namo brahmane
>
> Namaste Vaayuo.
>
> Tvameva prathyaksham brahmaasi!
>
> Tvaaameva, prathyaksham brahma vaadisham.
>
> Rtam vaadisham
>
> Satyama vaadisham.
>
> Tandmaa maavit.
>
> Tad-vaktaram aavit.
>
> Aveerna! Aavid vaktaram.

Is this version of the famous *Samnō miṭra* found in any of the Vedas/Upanishads.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following verse belongs to [Rigveda Mandala 1](http://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/rigveda/sanskrit03/RV0301noaccent.html), Sukta 90, Mantra 9:

> शं नो मित्रः शं वरुणः शं नो भवत्वर्यमा।
>   शं न इन्द्रो बृहस्पतिः शं नो विष्णुरुरुक्रमः॥ १.०९०.०९
>
> [9](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01090.htm). Be Mitra gracious unto us, and Varuṇa and Aryaman:
>   Indra, Bṛhaspati be kind, and Viṣṇu of the mighty stride.

The sloka you mentioned in the question is actually [Shanti Patha/Mantra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanti_Mantras) of Taittariya Shakha of Krishna Yajurveda, You can find it in [Taittariya Upanishad](https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_upanishhat/tait.html?lang=sa):

> **प्रथमा शीक्षावल्ली**
>
> ॐ शं नो मित्रः शं वरुणः । शं नो भवत्वर्यमा ।
>   शं न इन्द्रो बृहस्पतिः । शं नो विष्णुरुरुक्रमः ।
>   नमो ब्रह्मणे । नमस्ते वायो । त्वमेव प्रत्यक्षं ब्रह्मासि ।
>   त्वामेव प्रत्यक्षं ब्रह्म वदिष्यामि । ऋतं वदिष्यामि ।
>   सत्यं वदिष्यामि । तन्मामवतु । तद्वक्तारमवतु ।
>   अवतु माम् । अवतु वक्तारम् ।
>   ॐ शान्तिः शान्तिः शान्तिः ॥ १॥
>
> इति प्रथमोऽनुवाकः ॥

[English translation](http://www.shastras.com/upanishads-krishna-yajur-veda/taittiriya-upanishad/):

> I-i-1: May Mitra be blissful to us. May Varuna be blissful to us. May
>      Aryaman be blissful to us. May Indra and Brihaspati be blissful to us.
>      May Vishnu, of long strides, be blissful to us. Salutation to Brahman.
>      Salutation to you, O Vayu. You, indeed, are the immediate Brahman. You
>      alone I shall call the direct Brahman. I shall call you righteousness.
>      I shall call you truth. May He protect me. May He protect the teacher.
>      May He protect me. May He protect the teacher. Om, peace, peace, peace!